# How to delete profile from Workplace?

Tags: support, user-accounts

Now it seems like there has been lot of down vote lately for my answers. So Workplace won't allow me to add any more answers to questions.

So can someone give me link or steps to delete one's profile.

Comment: This should be probably asked in workplace meta

Comment: The reason your answers have been downvoted are probably the same reason that this question has been - you've not read or understood the [help]. For this particular question, see http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/answer-bans

Answer (score 8):

You can [delete your account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7979/165773) if you want, but if you're interested in participating here, it would be better to tackle the problem that's causing you to be blocked right now.  If you improve some of your downvoted posts so that they can be upvoted instead, the block will go away.  The block isn't meant to be *punitive*; it's there to keep people from flooding sites with low-quality posts.  We're not trying to make you go away; we're trying to put a temporary stop in place so that you can make improvements and then continue participating.

Enderland has given you some [specific advice](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2954/325) on your posts.  Please consider that, and any comments you received, and look over your posts with that in mind.

Answer (score 7):

Here is some context you might want to know why your answers are not being received well. Looking at your answers, it seems many of them are very short, more like "here's my thoughts" and do not necessarily comprehensively answer the question.

Specifically:

- https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/34585/2322

  - This is relatively presumptuous and not really worded well. I have a hard time following it, as well.
- https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/34584/2322, https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/34566/2322, https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/34565/2322,
  https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/34563/2322

  - None of these really address the question very comprehensively and doesn't explain "why is this right?" [This link](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) has some good advice on how to improve your answer.
- https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/34564/2322

  - Again, this is only tangentially answering the question and does not explain "why"

I think if you spend some time and focus your answers on:

- Answering the question
- Explaining "why is this right"

Many of them will receive upvotes and be better received.

Hope this helps!